# Why does device.device_report_product_code require = rather than :?

Tags: openfda

To successfully search the **device/event** endpoint for `device.device_report_product_code`, you must search using `=` instead of `:` like this:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.device_report_product_code="HQF"](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.device_report_product_code=%22HQF%22)

But the API documentation (to my knowledge) doesn't document the required use of `=` for `device.device_report_product_code`. Furthermore, if you use `:` instead of `=`, you don't get an error. You get "No results found!", which is what this query returns:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.device_report_product_code:"HQF"](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=device.device_report_product_code:%22HQF%22)

Yet **HQF** is a valid 3-letter device code. Can someone explain when `=` must be used and why `:` (which I thought meant "contains") returned no matches?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange bug - the API should be erroring with the use of an equal sign there. We'll open a bug report and investigate. In the meantime, the ':' version does return results and should be what is used.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!